# Multiple Component with Same Function Name in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using `react-native-material-menu`'s `popup` for showing menu options.

But the issue is, it's not working for multiple scenarios.

I mean when I click on first menu button, the same methods gets triggered and hence the same menu is opened every time.

What should be the better approach for to handle this particular scenario.

```
 _menu = null;

 setMenuRef = ref => {
     this._menu = ref;
 };

 hideMenu = () => {
     this._menu.hide();
 };

 showMenu = () => {
     this._menu.show();
 };


  <FlatList
      data={this.state.clientsList}
      renderItem={({ item }) => {
      return (
          <View style={styles.caseItem} >
              <Card style={styles.card}>
                  <CardItem>
                     <Body>
                        <View style={styles.rowTitle}>
                           <Text style={styles.title}>{item.FullName}</Text>
                           <Menu
                                ref={this.setMenuRef}
                                button={
                                   <Icon 
                                        type="Feather" 
                                        name="more-vertical" 
                                        onPress={this.showMenu} 
                                           style{{fontSize:20,color:'#555'}} 
                                     />
                             }>
                                <MenuItem onPress={this.hideMenu}>View</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem onPress={this.hideMenu}>Edit</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem onPress={this.hideMenu}>Delete </MenuItem>
                            </Menu>
                        </View>

                        <View>
                            <Text style={styles.lbl}>Email: <Text style={styles.lblValue}>{item.EmailID}</Text></Text>
                            <Text style={styles.lbl}>Client Type: <Text style={styles.lblValue}>{item.ClientType}</Text></Text>
                        </View>
                     </Body>
                  </CardItem>
               </Card>
            </View>
         );
      }}
      keyExtractor={item => item.ID}
   />
```

[Snack Here](https://snack.expo.io/@zain143/multiple-component-with-same-function)

Comment: Send the menu item index as a parameter to the hide function.

Comment: can you make an example?

Comment: use a map function instead of FlatList

Comment: @DhavalJardosh it's not working.

Comment: were you able to get the snack example ready?

Comment: @DhavalJardosh Updated Snack..

Comment: @DhavalJardosh any good news?

Comment: Got it....Please check this https://snack.expo.io/@dhavaljardosh/multiple-component-with-same-function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To handle the states in the correct way, you will need to create a new Class which will be handling just the `MenuItem`

The below code will work: Here is the [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@dhavaljardosh/multiple-component-with-same-function).

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import { Container, Content, Card, CardItem, Body, Icon } from "native-base";
import * as Font from "expo-font";
import Menu, { MenuItem, MenuDivider } from "react-native-material-menu";
// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from "./components/AssetExample";

export default class App extends React.Component {

  onView = () => {
    alert("Do something here");
    console.log("You can do what ever you want here");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.caseItem}>
          <Card style={styles.card}>
            <CardItem>
              <Body>
                <View style={styles.rowTitle}>
                  <Text style={styles.title}>John Doe</Text>
                  <CustomMenu onView={this.onView}/>
                </View>

                <View>
                  <Text style={styles.lbl}>
                    Email: <Text style={styles.lblValue}>john@yopmail.com</Text>
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={styles.lbl}>
                    Client Type: <Text style={styles.lblValue}>Individual</Text>
                  </Text>
                </View>
              </Body>
            </CardItem>
          </Card>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.caseItem}>
          <Card style={styles.card}>
            <CardItem>
              <Body>
                <View style={styles.rowTitle}>
                  <Text style={styles.title}>John Doe</Text>
                  <CustomMenu  onView={this.onView}/>
                </View>

                <View>
                  <Text style={styles.lbl}>
                    Email: <Text style={styles.lblValue}>john@yopmail.com</Text>
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={styles.lbl}>
                    Client Type: <Text style={styles.lblValue}>Individual</Text>
                  </Text>
                </View>
              </Body>
            </CardItem>
          </Card>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.caseItem}>
          <Card style={styles.card}>
            <CardItem>
              <Body>
                <View style={styles.rowTitle}>
                  <Text style={styles.title}>John Doe</Text>
                  <CustomMenu onView={this.onView} />
                </View>

                <View>
                  <Text style={styles.lbl}>
                    Email: <Text style={styles.lblValue}>john@yopmail.com</Text>
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={styles.lbl}>
                    Client Type: <Text style={styles.lblValue}>Individual</Text>
                  </Text>
                </View>
              </Body>
            </CardItem>
          </Card>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class CustomMenu extends React.Component {
  _menu = null;
  setMenuRef = ref => {
    this._menu = ref;
  };

  hideMenu = () => {
    this._menu.hide();
  };

  onViewClick = () => {
    const {onView} = this.props;
    onView();
    this.hideMenu();
  }

  showMenu = () => {
    this._menu.show();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Menu
        ref={this.setMenuRef}
        button={
          <Icon
            type="Feather"
            name="more-vertical"
            onPress={this.showMenu}
            style={{ fontSize: 20, color: "#555" }}
          />
        }
      >
        <MenuItem onPress={this.onViewClick}>View</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onPress={this.hideMenu}>Edit</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onPress={this.hideMenu}>Delete </MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: "#ecf0f1",
    padding: 8
  },
  rowTitle: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    width: "100%"
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 14,
    marginBottom: 5
  },
  lbl: {
    fontSize: 11,
    color: "#000"
  },
  lblValue: {
    fontSize: 11,
    color: "#555",
    fontWeight: "normal"
  },
  caseItem: {
    marginBottom: 0
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `FlatList` will iterate over the menu items, you need to maintain index for each iterable menu options.

You can check, you are passing `item` object within `renderItems` prop. So you can use the same `item.id` as a key to your child (iterable) component.

Since the child component now maintains an index, so now you can pass it in methods which will help you differentiate the event which got triggered from the child element.

I hope this might give you an idea about the issue.

Comment: I don't understand, can you show me any example of code please?